# Múltiples opciones en RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo que validar un `input`, el cual contiene un código de Contrato.

Los formatos pueden ser:

- `AAAXXXX` o `AAAXXXX/XX-XX` o `AAAXXXX/VXXXX`
- `AXXXXXX` o `AXXXXXX/VXXXX`

<sub>(Siendo `A` un caracter alfabético, `X` un dígito y el resto (`/ - V`) literales)</sub>

---

La regex que he planteado es esta:

```
/^((\w{3}\d{4}(\/\d{2}-\d{2})?)|(((\w\d{6})|(\w{3}\d{4}))(\/v\d{4})?))$/i
```

Tengo [unos casos de pruebas](https://regex101.com/r/jI13X2/4/tests) online. Funciona bien para todos los casos menos el último, que lo toma por válido cuando no debería:

```
C123456/30-02
```

**¿Cómo sería la [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) resultante para que cumpla todos los casos?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Es un error suponer que `\w` coincide sólo con letras, cuando coinciden `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` y `_` (equivale a [`[A-Za-z0-9_]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word)), por lo que el emparejamiento se hace con la primera opción encontrada (`AAAXXXX/XX-XX` ya que `A` incluye a `X`).

Éste podría ser el patrón correcto:

`^(([A-Za-z]{3}\d{4}(\/\d{2}-\d{2})?)|((([A-Za-z]\d{6})|([A-Za-z]{3}\d{4}))(\/v\d{4})?))$` [(ver en línea)](https://regex101.com/r/OiRTKx/1/tests)

Si no vas a hacer uso de los datos obtenidos en cada grupo de coincidencia, es mejor usar [paréntesis no capturadores (?:x)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-capturing-parentheses):

`^(?:[a-z]{3}\d{4}(?:\/(?:\d{2}-\d{2}|V\d{4}))?|[a-z]\d{6}(?:\/v\d{4})?)$` [(ver en línea)](https://regex101.com/r/OiRTKx/2/tests)

Por facilitar la depuración y el mantenimiento de la expresión regular mantengo los grupos tal y como los defines en tus reglas. No impactará al rendimiento ya que el código se ejecutará únicamente a petición del usuario (en el evento de envío del formulario).

Comment: :O pues vaya error, sí. muchas gracias por la presteza y eficacia ^^ aunque ten en cuenta que puse el `flag i` asi que no hace falta duplicar A-Za-z hehe

Comment: Cierto, no me di cuenta al hacer el fork :) Es un error más común de lo que pueda parecer y yo mismo lo he sufrido en varias ocasiones y seguro que lo volveré a cometer de nuevo xD Lo importante es que en algún momento se nos encienda la bombilla y nos acordemos del detalle ;)

Comment: si, es odioso encontrar fallos que son chorradas como esta... pero si, fijo que no me vuelve a pasar XDD gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 8):

La lógica de tu intento está perfecta, sólo hay que tener en cuenta:

- El error se genera porque `\w` coincide con `[A-Za-z\d_]`, por lo que también coincide con dígitos, y de ahí el error.
- Se están utilizando algunos grupos por demás. Por ejemplo,
  `^((A)|(B))$` es exactamente lo mismo que
  `^(A|B)$`

  - La [alternancia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-or) (`|` que funciona como un `or`) guarda la más baja precedencia luego de los paréntesis.
- En vez de utilizar [grupos de captura](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-capturing-parentheses) (con paréntesis), que guardan el texto que coincidió en memoria, siempre recomiendo utilizar un [grupo sin captura](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-capturing-parentheses): `(?:subpatrón)`.

---

**Expresión Regular**

```
/^[A-Z](?:[A-Z]{2}\d{4}(?:\/(?:\d{2}-\d{2}|V\d{4}))?|\d{6}(?:\/V\d{4})?)$/i
```

Como se ve, si bien podría haber agrupado las opciones `AAAXXXX`, `AXXXXXX`, `AAAXXXX/VXXXX` y `AXXXXXX/VXXXX` por un lado, y `AAAXXXX/XX-XX` por otro, estoy desenvolviendo de izquierda a derecha. El motor de regex siempre intenta una coincidencia de izquierda a derecha, por lo que presentar las opciones en ese orden, si bien puede generar un patrón más largo, suele ser más eficiente.

Así, por ejemplo, sólo se intentará la coincidencia con la primera letra 1 sola vez, sin generar *backtracking* hacia otras alternativas cuando un intento no coincida.

**Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/GChkQv/3/tests